# Object id not added to ngrx store entity

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm getting an array of posts from a post effect action that I try adding to the store. The problem is that only the 1st post object in the array is added, and wrongly so, as the id is missing (it comes back as _id from the backend, but I have the same setup for a group entity and it works just fine, the id is added automatically based on the_id property).
Any help would be much appreciated.

post effects:

```
getGroupPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(PostActions.getGroupPosts),
            switchMap(action => {
                return this.http
                    .get<{ posts: Post[] }>
                    (`${BACKEND_URL}/posts/${action.groupId}?pageSize=${action.pageSize}&currentPage=${action.pageNumber}`)
                    .pipe(
                        map(response => {
                            this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.groupPostsLoaded({ groupId: action.groupId }));
                            return {
                                type: PostActions.GET_GROUP_POSTS_SUCCESS,
                                posts: response.posts
                            };
                        }),
                        catchError(err => this.handleError(err, PostActions.GET_GROUP_POSTS_FAILED))
                    );
            })
        )
    );

    getGroupPostsSucess$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$
            .pipe(
                ofType(PostActions.getGroupPostsSuccess),
                map(action => {
                    return {
                        type: SpinnerActions.STOP_SPINNER
                    };
                })
            )
    );
```

post reducer:

```
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Post } from 'src/app/models/post.model';
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as PostActions from './post.actions';

export interface PostState extends EntityState<Post> { }

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Post>();

export const initPostsState = adapter.getInitialState();

export const postReducer = createReducer(
    initPostsState,
    on(PostActions.createPostSuccess, (state, action) => {
        return adapter.addOne(action.post, { ...state });
    }),
    on(PostActions.getGroupPostsSuccess, (state, action) => {
        console.log(action);

        return adapter.addMany(action.posts, { ...state });
    })
);

export const {
    selectAll,
} = adapter.getSelectors();
```

group effects :

```
getTopicGroups$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(GroupActions.getTopicGroups),
            switchMap(action => {
                this.topic = action.topic;
                return this.http
                    .get<{ groups: Group[], count: number }>(
                        `${BACKEND_URL}/groups/${this.topic}?pageNumber=${action.pageNumber}&pageSize=${action.pageSize}`)
                    .pipe(
                        map(response => {
                            return {
                                type: GroupActions.GET_TOPIC_GROUPS_SUCCESS,
                                groups: response.groups,
                                topic: this.topic,
                                count: response.count,
                                groupsLoaded: response.groups.length
                            };
                        }),
                        catchError(err => this.handleError(err, GroupActions.GET_TOPIC_GROUPS_FAILED))
                    );
            })
        )
);

getTopicGroupSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(GroupActions.getTopicGroupsSuccess),
            map(action => {
                return {
                    type: SpinnerActions.STOP_SPINNER
                };
            })
        )
);
```

group reducers:

```
export interface GroupState extends EntityState<Group> {
    topicsLoaded: {
        topic: string,
        count: number,
        groupsLoaded: number
    }[];
}

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Group>();

export const initialGroupState = adapter.getInitialState({
    topicsLoaded: []
});

export const groupReducer = createReducer(
    initialGroupState,
    on(GroupActions.getTopicGroupsSuccess, (state, action) => {
        let oldTopics;
        let newTopics;
        // Check if 1st batch of groups have already been loaded //
        const oldGroupsLoaded = state.topicsLoaded.find(g => g.topic === action.topic);

        if (!oldGroupsLoaded) {
            // Add topic to group entity //
            newTopics = [...state.topicsLoaded];
            newTopics.push({
                topic: action.topic,
                count: action.count,
                groupsLoaded: action.groupsLoaded
            });
        } else {
            // Update group entity //
            const index = [...state.topicsLoaded].indexOf(oldGroupsLoaded);
            oldTopics = [...state.topicsLoaded];
            oldTopics[index] = {
                ...state.topicsLoaded[index],
                groupsLoaded: state.topicsLoaded[index].groupsLoaded + action.groupsLoaded
            };
        }
        return adapter.addMany(action.groups,
            {
                ...state,
                topicsLoaded: oldGroupsLoaded ? oldTopics : newTopics
            });
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it turns out you have to create a method for the selectId property on the entity adapter... but somehow you don't if you add properties to it (like in the group entity adapter)

```
export interface PostState extends EntityState<Post> {
    selectPostId: string;
}

export const selectPostId = (post: Post) => post._id;

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Post>({
    selectId: selectPostId
});
```